# Order page after likes by friends

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

It is easy to get the likes of a page on Facebook and order them by numbers, as found [here](http://peterbending.com/wordpress/how-to-order-posts-by-number-of-facebook-likes/).

But how do you get the number of likes from a user's friends?

For example, I want to be able to make a text to show "2 of your friends likes this page exact on www.example.com", preferably without them having to accept a Facebook app.

Just like when you click a like button, some of your friends already clicked on. "Friend, Friend and 100 others has liked this page."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to prompt the user for extended permissions to get this information.  You won't be able to access any users friends information without authentication with your application.  The closest you could do is show a like button for that url by setting the href property of the like button and then styling the button by applying css to hide the actual like button, leaving just the "2 friends like this page" text.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I just thought it was possible, but than you for the answer! :)